# Generation of an array of substring from a string in swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I have a problem with generation of an array of substrings from a string in the following code

```
var primers=[String]()

var lengthOfPrimer = 20

var  lentghOfText = str1.characters.count

var rest = lentghOfText - lengthOfPrimer

for var i = 0; i <= str1.characters.count; ++i
{

var temp = rest - i

var substring1 = str1.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(str1.startIndex, i), end: advance(str1.endIndex, -temp)))

primers.append(substring1)

}
```

In playground I have the following error at the line with the substring1 code – Execution was interrupted: reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC 1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0. 
In spite of error sign, I can see in playground the generated set of substrings in loop, but when I tried to use this code in program this code also did not work, What is wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from trying to `advance` the `endIndex`.

But how about something a little simpler? (Swift 2)

```
var first = str1.startIndex
var last = advance(first, 20 - 1, str1.endIndex)

while last != str1.endIndex {
    primers.append(str1[first++ ... last++])
}

print("\n".join(primers))

// output:
// ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCC
// CAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCG
// AAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGG
// AGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGC
// GATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCC
// ATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCT
// TGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTC
// GCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCC
// CCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCT
// CATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTG
// ATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGC
// TTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCT
// ...
```

Or the `for` loop way:

```
for var first = str1.startIndex, last = advance(first, 20 - 1, str1.endIndex);
    last != str1.endIndex;
    ++first, ++last
{
    primers.append(str1[first...last])
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the working code! I have played with another for loop code and try to modify it as you can see below and it did not work. Sorry, I am new in swift and would like to understand why code did not work.  Could you give me the explanation?                                                               for var i = 0; i < lengthOfText - 1; ++i {  primers.append(str1[advance(str1.startIndex, i)...advance(str1.startIndex, i + 20) ] ) }

Comment: I would not recommend doing it that way. `++` for a string may be slow because it has to determine where the character boundary is. `advance` is like multiple `++`s. So it's best to do it as little as possible. In my version above, I use `++` only twice per iteration.

Comment: You should also keep in mind what happens when the string is exactly 20 characters or shorter.

Comment: I have used your suggestion with C-like for-loop and now after coming deprecations of  both C-like for-loop  and ++ , I am using instead while-loop with .successor, but it works two time slower than the same while loop with ++. Is there way to improve the execution time of this while loop with  .successor instead of ++  or no ?

Comment: Are you building/running the code with optimization on (`-O`)?

Comment: No, I have compared two variants in playground by using: let date_start = NSDate()  - code to perform  - print("\(-date_start.timeIntervalSinceNow)").

Comment: Testing performance is a good idea, but it's not meaningful if you haven't enabled optimization! You can put your code in a `.swift` file and use `swift -O myfile.swift` to run it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for var i = 0; i <= str1.characters.count; ++i
```

Without getting into the rest of this code, this for loop is wrong. You are reading past the end of the string because you are using <= when you should be using <.

Also you are calling str1.characters.count in the loop even though you have that value in a variable, which is slow.

Try:

```
for var i = 0; i < lengthOfText; ++i
```

Comment: I have tried, and it still not working with your correction.

Comment: Well yeah, you have other bugs too, I'm sure. I just pointed out the ones that jumped off the screen at me.